# TinyMCE not using the correct format for strike-through

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I'm attempting to change the default formatting for strikethrough and underline in TinyMCE5 to use 's' and 'u' tags. The [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/) suggest that the first item in the format will be used and the remaining lines will be used for selecting the matching tags.

Regardless of what I do, the strikethough renders as a span with 'line-through' text-decoration styling, whereas the underline inserts a 'u' element.

TinyMCE displays the correct tag (ie p > s ) in the markup path at the bottom of the editor, but when viewing the source it uses a span.

Ideas?

```
formats: {
            strikethrough: [
                { inline: 's',},
                { inline: 'strike'},
                { inline: 'span', styles: { 'text-decoration': 'line-through' }},
            ],
            underline: [
                { inline: 'u',},
                { inline: 'span', styles: { 'text-decoration': 'underline' }},
            ],
        },
```

Comment: If you want to play around with the configuration of TinyMCE, check out the Fiddle Tool (http://fiddle.tiny.cloud) for all your debugging, and experiments

Answer (score 0):

Having had a closer look, it appears that we were using the wrong format in the valid_elements so TinyMCE thought that the 's' and 'strike' tags weren't valid.